# Comparing two integrals of a piecewise function

Tags: integration

i want to find a factor that will give the same results for the next integral :
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^2|f(x)|^2dx 
$$ 
Let's say that $f(x)$ is defined as :

I.
\begin{equation}
f_1(x)=
 \begin{cases}
 1,& \text{for } 0 \leq x \leq 10 \\
 0,& \text{otherwise}\\
 \end{cases}.
\end{equation}

II.
\begin{equation}
f_2(x)=
 \begin{cases}
 0,& \text{for } 0 \leq x \leq 2 \\
 1,& \text{for } 2 < x \leq 6 \\
    0,& \text{for } 6 < x \leq 8 \\
    1,& \text{for } 8 < x \leq 10 \\
 \end{cases}.
\end{equation}

I am searching for $\alpha f_1(x)$ such that integrating I will give the same result as integrating II.

$f(x)$ represent a pulse, were $x$ is the frequency. So I thought that I can solve this problem just by considering the energy aspect and say that $\alpha f_1(x)$ have the same energy as $f_2(x)$, hence I can calculate the integral on $\alpha f_1(x)$ and get the same results

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do here is calculate it!

Let
$$ f_1(x) = \begin{cases} 1, \ x \in [0,10] \\ 0, \ x \not \in [0,10] \end{cases}$$
and
$$ \alpha f_2(x) = \begin{cases} \alpha, \ x \in (2,6] \cup (8,10]\\ 0, \ x \not \in (2,6] \cup (8,10] \end{cases}$$
Now we wish to find $\alpha$ such that
$$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty x^2 |f_1(x)|^2 \ dx = \int_{\infty}^\infty x^2|\alpha f_2(x)|^2$$
This is the same thing as computing which $\alpha$ satisfies
$$ \int_0^{10} x^2 \ dx = \int_2^6 x^2 \alpha^2 \ dx + \int_8^{10} x^2 \alpha^2 \ dx$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes, but I want to expand my question to more general solution so I will edit it.